# Could not find gem 'wdm (>= 0.1.0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine

Tags: ruby, jekyll, devkit

When I run Jekyll serve on Git Bash I get the following warning:

```
Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
```

After adding the Gemfile I get another error message.

```
Could not find gem 'wdm (>= 0.1.0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
```

I tried installing Ruby Devkit to fix this issue but I only end up getting the following error messages.

```
$ ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby200-x64'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby200-x64'

$ gem install json --platform=ruby
ERROR: Error installing json:
The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `bundle install` after adding the `wdm` gem to your Gemfile to download it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have installed devkit before, and it skips the new installation, try

```
ruby dk.rb install --force
```

Comment: One should really follow the steps at https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit to install the devkit. Then, it perfectly works also when using [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/) - `choco install ruby2.devkit`.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add wdm into bundle after downloading it. Try

`bundle add wdm`